# "Failed to deploy project to App Engine Flex"

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-webapi

First time using GCP and I'm trying to upload a .NET project.

I cannot manage to publish the app using the integrated tools from Visual Studio, "Google Cloud Tools" and I get this message "Failed to deploy project to App Engine Flex".

I also tried using Cloud Run or the Google Cloud SDK Shell using `gcloud app deploy app.yml` but i get this error now:

```
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I know it's coming from the Dockerfile but I don't know how to use and write it. Here it is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

COPY./sims/sims.csproj.sims/sims.csproj
COPY .sln./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o build --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from= build./ build.
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS = https://:8080
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "sims.dll"]
```

Here's my .yaml file in case it might come from here:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Do you have any advice ?

Also, concerning these two files, I don't even know if they're located in the right repository: [project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M4Ox.jpg)

Thanks for reading

Comment: Curious if you found a solution for this?